# Does NSFileWrapper support lazy loading?

Tags: macos, cocoa, lazy-loading, nsdocument, nsfilewrapper

I am creating a `NSDocument` package that contains potentially hundreds of large files, so I don't want to read it all in when opening the document.

I've spent some time searching, but I can't find a definitve answer.  Most people seem to think that `NSFileWrapper` loads all of the data into memory, but some indicate that it doesn't load data until you invoke `-regularFileContents` on a wrapper.  (See [Does NSFileWrapper load everything into memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621502/does-nsfilewrapper-load-everything-into-memory) and [Objective-C / Cocoa: Uploading Images, Working Memory, And Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250166/objective-c-cocoa-uploading-images-working-memory-and-storage) for examples.)

The documentation isn't entirely clear, but options like `NSFileWrapperReadingImmediate` and `NSFileWrapperReadingWithoutMapping` seem to suggest that it doesn't always read everything in.

I gather that `NSFileWrapper` supports incremental saving, only writing out sub-wrappers that have been replaced.  So it'd be nice if it supports incremental loading too.

Is there a definitive answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSFileWrapper` loads lazily by default, unless you specify the `NSFileWrapperReadingImmediate` option. It will avoid reading a file into memory until something actually requests it.

As a **debugging aid only**, you can see whether a file has been loaded yet, by examining:

```
[wrapper valueForKey:@"_contents"];
```

It gets filled in as `NSData` once the file is read from disk.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.  Am I correct in thinking that if I specify `NSFileWrapperReadingWithoutMapping`, then `-regularFileContents` will read in the file without caching it?  I want to be able to read in a bunch of plists without having them remain in memory.  Even better would be to let it cache them, and have a way to unload/discard them when no longer needed, but I don't see any method for that.

Comment: No, `NSFileWrapperReadingWithoutMapping` controls whether memory mapping should be used or not. Either way, an `NSData` object to cover the file will be held onto

Comment: The only way to "unload" a file wrapper without deallocating it is to ask it to read from a URL again. Arguably this is a deliberate design so that under normal circumstances, `NSFileWrapper` behaves semi-immutably; once loaded, its properties don't revert backwards to an earlier/unknown state

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'll try to minimize the loading of file contents, then (no doubt a good idea for performance, anyway).